# Fastest way to send several HTTP Post request for iOS?

Tags: ios, http, post, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I need to send around 20 HTTP Post requests in my iOS Application. Right now I am using NSURLConnection and sending the 20 requests one by one, which of course takes a long time. Each connection starts after the previous, taken around 7 seconds to complete all the requests. Is it possible to send these 20 requests simultaneously and receive the JSON result much faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` to prepare all of the requests and push them onto the queue at the same time. Then you can set the concurrent execution limit to determine how many run at the same time. Don't run all 20 at the same time though as you may flood the network and prevent any of the connections from completing properly. Try running 5 concurrently and see how it goes.